# jquery tabbed content creates page shift

Tags: css, jquery, tabs

I am using jquery tabbed content and I have noticed when navigating to any tab other than the product tab the page shifts a few pixels to the right and then when clicking the product tab it shifts back. What in the world is causing this?

The link to see it in action, http://clients.zerozendesign.info/techject/

Comment: Are you using the JQueryUI Tabs from (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)? It sounds like you have an issue with CSS, perhaps a rule is being applied to elements on your Product tab that is not affecting elements on the other tabs? Adding more information to your question will help to get  the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the presence of the scroll bar on the long page content on the products tab.   You should consider displaying the scroll bar even when the content does not require it using the CSS property for overflow, like so:

```
html { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

Comment: @CoplanConsulting You should upvote and accept his answer, too. :)